# How to pass an object with an array of other objects from one fragment to another?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have one object, let's call it `Shop`, and this object has an array of objects called `Offers`.
How should I use `Bundle` with my object to send it from a 1st Fragment to the one I open with a `onClickListener`?

Beeing `Shop`, the object I need to parse something like:

```
public class Shop {

    private String name;
    private String schedule;
    private String direction;
    private List<Offer> Offers = new ArrayList<Offer>();
}
```

and `Offer` Something like :

```
public class Offer {

    private int packsAvailable;
    private String description;
}
```

and that function calls the second fragment:

```
public void onClick(View v) {


    Fragment shopping = new OffersDisplayFragment();

    //Instantiate fragment
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, shopping);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Be more specific, & include code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding a method to create an Instance of the next Fragment (I assume it is the OffersDisplayFragment).

Add the following method to your fragment so we can create Fragment with bundle:

```
public class OffersDisplayFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String SHOP_EXTRA = "shopExtra";

    // Creates a new fragment given a Shop
    public static OffersDisplayFragment newInstance(Shop shop) {
        OffersDisplayFragment fragment = new OffersDisplayFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(SHOP_EXTRA, shop);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Then update or create onCreate method of your fragment to handle the bundle:

```
public class OffersDisplayFragment extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Get back arguments
       Shop = (Shop) getArguments().getSerializable(SHOP_EXTRA);

       // Do something with the Shop here   
   }
}
```

in this point, Android Studio will complaining that your `Shop` model can't be serialized. This is expected, because we haven't declare the Shop as `serializable`. So, change your Shop and Offer as serializable like this:

```
public class Shop implements Serializable {
  ...
}
```

and

```
public class Offer implements Serializable {
  ...
}
```

Now, you can create the fragment with the bundle in your click listener like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Fragment shoppingFragment = OffersDisplayFragment.newInstance(shop);

    ...
    // show the fragment with the fragment transaction.
}
```

---

After you have a working solution, try using `Parcelable` instead `Serializable`.